# C# problem when make phone call by Android device using PC

Tags: c#, winforms, phone-call

I have written a program to make call from pc using C#.

```
SerialPort po = new SerialPort();
po.PortName = textBox1.Text.ToUpper();

po.BaudRate = int.Parse("9600");
po.DataBits = Convert.ToInt32("8");
po.Parity = Parity.None;
po.StopBits = StopBits.One;
po.ReadTimeout = int.Parse("500");
po.WriteTimeout = int.Parse("500");
po.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
po.Open();
po.DtrEnable = true;
po.RtsEnable = true;

if (!po.IsOpen)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Serial port is not opened");
    return;
}

po.WriteLine("ATD=\"" + "111;" + "\"" + Environment.NewLine);
po.Close();
```

When I press button to make a call, I get this error:

> System.IO.IOException: 'The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

On this line:

```
po.WriteLine("ATD=\"" + "111;" + "\"" + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: try Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() and see what it show you in the error.

Comment: plez help me how to do it]

Comment: any help plez .